# Borrar un commit en GitHub

Tags: git

Tengo un repositorio en **GitHub** y me he dado cuenta que cometí un error. En primer lugar, lo que hice con mi **PRIMER** commit, junto a su git push, fue subir todo mi proyecto, pero con él, fueron **KEYS** que no deberían haber sido publicadas.

Lo que hice fue directamente editarlo desde GitHub y borrar esa claves, haciendo un **segundo** commit directamente en la rama master.

Entonces, al momento, tengo la siguiente history:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El **primer** commit es el que quiero borrar, por que cuando se entra en él, se ven las KEYS.

Se que debería haberlo puesto en el gitignore en un principio, pero lo olvide. Espero que se halla entendido, muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque lo puedes solucionar a base de comandos, (tendrías que hacer git push --force origin master para machacar la rama master)  y teniendo en cuenta que solo llevas un par de commits, a lo mejor te es más fácil borrar el proyecto desde la interfaz web de github y crearlo de nuevo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es eliminar el commit del historial, ejecuta :

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

Donde "commit" es el SHA-1 de 40 caracteres,o la abreviatura de 7 del identificador del commit.

Si lo que deseas es eliminar el commit, pero mantener los cambios que se introdujeron , entonces ejecuta :

```
git reset <commit>
```

Puedes echar un vistazo a este [enlace](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#remove_last) donde se explican como resolver diferentes casuísticas de commits erroneos y diferentes comandos para cada una.

Espero que te sirva.